# Remove border from multiple plots of Stacked and Grouped Column chart (Highcharts.js)

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have created a `Stacked and Grouped column chart` using `Highcharts.js`, for leaves section, i.e it has 31,28,30 days depending upon the month and shows the leaves accordingly. Snapshot given below:

[image]

If we see carefully, we have multiple sections created as per the code, which is bifurcated by `borderColor:'black'` and `borderWidth:1`.

I want to remove these internal borders and instead give a parent border to the whole chart, something as below:

[image]

**The js code is as belows:**

```
function convertToStackedFormat(data)
{
    var array1 = new Array();
    $.each(data, function (index, element) {
        if (element.length > 0)
        {
            $.each(element, function () {
                array1.push(this);
            });
        }
    });
    return array1;
}

function displayLeaveDetails(data) {
    var data1 = convertToJsonObjectArray(data);
    data1 = convertToStackedFormat(data1);

    Highcharts.chart('leaveContainer', {
        chart: {
            type: 'column'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Leaves'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: [
                'Jan',
                'Feb',
                'Mar',
                'Apr',
                'May',
                'Jun',
                'Jul',
                'Aug',
                'Sep',
                'Oct',
                'Nov',
                'Dec'
            ]
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            max: 35,
            tickInterval: 5,
            endOnTick: false,
            title: {
                text: 'Leaves (days)'
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            formatter: function () {
                return this.point.color=="white"?null:this.point.y;
            }
        },
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                stacking: 'normal',
                borderWidth: 1,
                borderColor: 'black'
            }
        },
        series: [{
            stack:0,
            name: 'Leaves',
            data: data1
        }]
    });
}
```

Can it be achieved by setting some attribute via `Highcharts.js`?

Please help.

Comment: Do you think you could providing a working example?

Comment: @Deckerz  http://jsfiddle.net/s38b1o9z/2/  This is a similar working example. Please have a look.

Comment: Doesn't look like its possible because its using SVG which doesn't support borders

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this by setting the `plotOptions column shadow object`, and putting the color of the border color to `white`.

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Leaves'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['jan', 'feb', 'march', 'april', 'may']
    },
    yAxis: {
        allowDecimals: false,
        min: 0,
        title: {
            text: 'Leaves'
        }
    },
    tooltip: {
        formatter: function () {
            return '<b>' + this.x + '</b><br/>' +
                this.series.name + ': ' + this.y + '<br/>' +
                'Total: ' + this.point.stackTotal;
        }
    },
    plotOptions: {
        column: {
            stacking: 'normal',
                borderWidth: 1,
                borderColor: 'white',
                shadow: {
            color: 'black',
            width: 5,
            opacity: 0.2,
            offsetY: -1,
            offsetX: 1
        }
        }
    },
    series: [{
            stack:0,
            name: 'Leaves',
            data: [{x:0,y:1,color:'white'},
            {x:0,y:1,color:'white'},
            {x:0,y:1,color:'white'},
            {x:0,y:1,color:'white'},
            {x:0,y:1,color:'white'},
            {x:0,y:1,color:'white'},
            {x:0,y:1,color:'white'},
            {x:0,y:1,color:'white'},
            {x:0,y:1,color:'white'},
            {x:0,y:1,color:'white'},
            {x:0,y:1,color:'white'},
            {x:0,y:1,color:'white'},
            {x:0,y:1,color:'white'},
            {x:0,y:3,color:'red'},
            {x:0,y:1,color:'white'},
            {x:0,y:1,color:'white'},
            {x:1,y:1,color:'white'},
            {x:1,y:1,color:'white'},
            {x:1,y:1,color:'white'},
            {x:1,y:1,color:'white'},
            {x:1,y:1,color:'white'},
            {x:1,y:1,color:'white'},
            {x:1,y:1,color:'white'},
            {x:1,y:5,color:'red'},
            {x:1,y:1,color:'white'},
            {x:1,y:1,color:'white'},
            ]
        }]
});
```

JS Fiddle link is as follows:

http://jsfiddle.net/s38b1o9z/5/

It's not a perfect solution, but it works.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The second solution would be to create another series, which would contain total values for all months, to be used as a border. Simply, link this series to the 'Leaves' series with `linkedTo` property, set its `color` to transparent, set different `stack` value and disable `grouping`. You can also turn off mouse tracking for this series with `enableMouseTracking` property.

API Reference:
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.column.grouping
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.column.linkedTo

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/8Ljmv4ud/